# How to execute linux commands from R via bash under the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)?

Tags: r, windows, delphi, windows-subsystem-for-linux

The WSL on Windows 10 allows execution of Linux commands and command-line tools via bash.exe. Very usefully, a Linux tool/command can be called from the Windows command-line (`cmd.exe`) by passing it as an argument to bash.exe like so:

```
bash.exe -c <linux command>
```

This is very useful because it should allow Windows-based scripts to combine Windows and Linux tools seamlessly.

Unfortunately, I have failed to call Linux commands from an R script (see below).

**0) System**

Win10 x64 + Anniversary Update + WSL installed

**1) Comparison cases where calling Linux commands work**

The following all work for me; shown here just with an example call to `ls`.

- from the windows command-line (cmd.exe prompt)

  ```
  bash -c "ls /mnt/a"
  ```

  ```
  bash -c "ls /mnt/a > /mnt/a/test.txt"
  ```
- Same works if started from <kbd>WinKey + R</kbd>
- Same works from within a `.bat` file.
- It can be called from compiled code. I tried with Delphi XE2 32-bit and 64-bit using `ShellExecute`:

  For example, these work (32 and 64 bit):

  ```
  ShellExecute (0, PChar('open'), PChar('cmd.exe'), PChar('/c c:\windows\system32\bash.exe -c "ls /mnt/a > /mnt/a/test.txt"'), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  ```

  Or (32-bit code):

  ```
  ShellExecute (0, PChar('open'), PChar('c:\windows\sysnative\bash.exe'), PChar('-c "ls /mnt/a > /mnt/a/test.txt"'), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  ```

  Or (64-bit code):

  ```
  ShellExecute (0, PChar('open'), PChar('c:\windows\system32\bash.exe'), PChar('-c "ls /mnt/a > /mnt/a/test.txt"'), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
  ```

  All of these seem to work (and `ShellExecute` returns 42).

**2) Failure to call Linux commands from R**
using R 3.3.1 x64

All of the below (and several similar things I've tried) fail with status 65535:

```
shell('c:/windows/system32/bash.exe -c "ls /mnt/a"', shell="cmd.exe", flag = "/c")
```

```
shell("ls", shell="c:/windows/system32/bash.exe", flag = "-c")
```

```
system('cmd /c c:/windows/system32/bash.exe -c "ls /mnt/a > /mnt/a/test.txt"')
```

```
system('bash -c "ls /mnt/a"')
```

```
system('c:/windows/system32/bash.exe -c "ls /mnt/a > /mnt/a/test.txt"')
```

**3) Question**

Given that examples under *1)* work, I find *2)* very puzzling. Am I missing anything obvious here?

I would be very grateful for a simple example where running a Linux command via `bash.exe` under WSL works.

Comment: Any failure diagnostics?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan  system('bash [...]') returns 65535 and issues a warning msg: Warning message:
running command '[...]' had status 65535. Same for shell. I haven't been able to get anything more useful than that.

Comment: Can you run any other programs, or is Bash the only one you've tried?

Comment: @RobKennedy Calling things using system() or shell() usually works like a charm in R. Some simple examples: shell("dir",shell="cmd.exe",flag = "/c"); system("cmd /c dir"); system ("c:/windows/system32/attrib.exe"). Bash.exe is the first one I've come across displaying this behaviour.

Comment: I should perhaps add that, if anybody tries to reproduce the above, the automatically mounted Windows drives will of course depend on the host machine, so you might have to change "/mnt/a" for another path. I suppose "/mnt/c" should be available everywhere.

Comment: Does it work if you replace bash.exe with `C:\Windows\sysnative\bash.exe`? I had the same problem in a non-elevated cmd prompt (but not in an elevated).

Comment: @LennartSchedin Thx, interesting. It still fails, although this time with a different error code, 127.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your failing examples should now be working correctly in Windows 10 Insider builds >= 14951 which [introduced many "interop" improvements and new capabilities](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/10/19/interop-between-windows-and-bash/):

```
> system('bash -c "ls /"')
```

Generates:

```
bin   cache  dev  home  lib    media  opt   root  sbin  srv  tmp  var
boot  data   etc  init  lib64  mnt    proc  run   snap  sys  usr
```

Comment: thanks for this info, that sounds brilliant. I can't test this at the moment, but once I can, I'll accept the answer

Comment: Just out of curiosity - it seems that my examples from compiled code worked because I used ShellExecute; when trying to use CreateProcess, it only worked as long as I didn't try to change bash.exe's standard output handle. Was I on the right track with that?

Comment: ShellExecute() does a ton more, taking into account your shell extensions, environment settings, x86/x64 bitness path mapping etc. This likely results in the correct bash.exe being called for your environment.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks! I was able to run plink (a bioinformatics tool) using the Windows Linux Subsystem this way. Example: system('bash -c plink1 --help')

Comment: Great to hear. Note - bash.exe remains for back-compat, but I encourage you to execute its replacement - wsl.exe instead, which offers MANY more options and methods of control.

Comment: I'm trying to use `system("wsl -u fons my_cmd some_args")` because `my_cmd` is not available for `bash -c` (I get `127`). The `wsl -u fons` version runs fine if I just open a powershell instance. Is there anything else I'm missing?

Comment: PS: I've just moved the executable to a system-wide accessible location and `bash -c` works but I'm generally curious as to whether the `wsl -u someone` option should also work in principle

Comment: @FonsMA Please create a new question rather than piggybacking in the comments of an unrelated question.